# Send requests to desktop application server

Tags: c#, .net, server

I have the following questions:

I am creating a desktop application (Windows), and I wish the same send solitudes and interact with another application running stored in server (Windows Server), I'm programming in C #.

Is there any way? With some protocol or something related? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a LOT of ways to do it.

1. In modern way, use Server: [ASP.NET WebApi](http://www.asp.net/web-api) and desktop application: [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781239.aspx). This is called REST and most popular in these days.
2. In Windows way, use Server: [WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and desktop application: [WebService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Not recommended for simple service.
3. Oldies but goodies way: use [Socket programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Many folks might recommend to use REST. Try to find tutorials related on **C#** and **Rest**. There's hundreds of good articles so cannot pick one of it in this reply.